# Error trying to copy certain file types over to a new directory

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have a file filled with photos called 'flashmem' (/root/flashmem), I am trying to move all photos in the format IMG_0000.JPG as you can see from the regex into another directory called 'photoarch' (/root/photoarch)($1), I want to move all duplicates into a txt file ($2).
Below I have attached my code, what i'm typing into the command line showing my errors as well as what my root directory looks like. Any help is appreciated, I have been trying to get this working for ages so please no negative feedback on this question! Thanks.

Command line error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dethl.jpg
My root directory: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Un27C.jpg

```
#!/bin/sh
if ["$#" -ne2 ]; then
    echo "Illegal number of parameters"
fi
find "$1" -regextype posix-extended -regex 'IMG_[0-9]{4}\.[JPG]{3}$' -exec cp --backup=numbered -t "$2" \;
find "$2" -type f-exec md5sum '{}' ';' |sort| uniq--all-repeated=separate-w 32 > /root/duplicate.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of syntax errors in the script.

- Should be `[ $# -ne 2 ]` instead of `["$#" -ne2 ]`
- Should probably `exit` with non-zero if there are no 2 parameters
- The `-exec cp ...` in the `find` command lacks the parameter placeholder `{}`
- The second `find` pipeline has many options stuck together without separating spaces
- The regex `IMG_[0-9]{4}\.[JPG]{3}$` in the first `find` looks weird. Why not end with `JPG` instead of `[JPG]{3}`?

Putting the above together, this should work better:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Illegal number of parameters"
    exit 1
fi

find "$1" -regextype posix-extended -regex 'IMG_[0-9]{4}\.JPG$' -exec cp --backup=numbered -t {} "$2" \;
find "$2" -type f -exec md5sum '{}' ';' | sort | uniq --all-repeated=separate -w 32 > /root/duplicate.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Janos, apologies for the multiple syntax errors, very tired! haha, ill try this out and get back to you, thanks :)

Comment: Janos, although this code now runs without any errors it doesn't seem to move any photos to (/root/photoarch) ($1), any ideas? Thanks, Joe.

Comment: @JoeBloggs run `find "$1" -regextype posix-extended -regex 'IMG_[0-9]{4}\.JPG$' | head` to verify that it actually matches any files at all. If you get empty output, then we need to work more on that `find` command.

Comment: tried running this line and I still got an empty output so there must be an issue with my find command, ill look into it and get back to you, thanks for all the help :)!